# PL/SQL: How can I calculate the AGE knowing a column called Birth_Date?

Tags: plsql

I have a table consisting of one column `(BIRTH_DATE)`. How could I use sysdate to subtract from all the rows of my `BIRTH_DATE` and `GROUP BY` them together?

to be more clear:

Here is what I have fetched, now I would like to add an AGE Column to the below Table for all rows

```
ID     Birth_Date
___    ___________
1       02-JAN-63
2       23-OCT-31
3       30-DEC-35
4       06-MAY-83
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to be more clear: Why do you feel you need to group by? What does the raw data look like? Are you trying to add the age column to the table or your result set?

Comment: I need to 'group by' by age because I need to determine the oldest and the youngest of the list. The raw data is just that example table up top. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a person's age according to the usual criterion (i.e. according to the number of calendar years that have passed since their birth), taking into account leap years, you can use the MONTHS_BETWEEN operator:

```
SELECT id, MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, birth_date) / 12 age FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply subtract `birth_date` from `sysdate`:

```
select id, (sysdate - birth_date) / 365 age from my_table;
```

Subtracting dates results in the number of days, so dividing by 365 will give you decimal years.

Comment: Note, however, that there are more than 365 days per year, on average :)

Answer (score 3):

SELECT TRUNC(months_between(SYSDATE, birthDate) / 12) AS age

Answer (score 3):

Its been a long time. Hope this helps.

```
declare
   patAge int;
   patName patient.fname%type;
   cursor agePat is 
      SELECT fname, MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, dob) / 12 age FROM patient;
begin
   open agePat;
   loop
      fetch agePat into patName, patAge;
      exit when agePat%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line('Patient Age = ' || patAge || ' || Patient Name = ' || patName);
   end loop;
   close agePat;
end;
/
```

patAge here is to store the age value and patName to store the value of patient's name in the table.

I turned @JeffreyKemp solution into pl sql code.